# Replacing multiple values in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to quickly replace values in a firebase snapshot based on certain criteria. For example, I'm looking to replace all "username" with the value "xyz" where userId = userId_0001 (userId is not unique). This is my code so far:

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("usernames").queryOrdered(byChild: "userId").queryEqual(toValue: "userId_0001")
    databaseRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        
            for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
                username.setValue("xyz")
    })

}
```

[image]

Comment: That code looks fine to me at first glance. What's the problem when you run it?

Comment: Is it the typo of the user ID? The image shows `userId_001` and your code refers to `userId_0001`.

Comment: There are a number of issues with that code. As is, it won't compile nor run and I am not sure what this is supposed to be doing; `value?["username"] as? String ??`. Even if it compiled, userName would be a string so `username.setValue("xyz")` is not going to work. I think you're trying to set that value in Firebase? If so, check the Getting Started Guide [Write Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#write_data). Can you include the actual code you've attempted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code in the question and the query value in the code (`userId_0001`) doesn't match the value in the screen shot (`userId_001`)

From what I gather, you want to query firebase for nodes with a userId of `userId_001` (which matches your screenshot) and for those nodes, replace the existing `username` value with `xyz`

Here's the code that will do that

```
func replacer() {
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("usernames").queryOrdered(byChild: "userId").queryEqual(toValue: "userId_0001")
    databaseRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        let childSnaps = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for snap in childSnaps {
            snap.ref.child("username").setValue("xyz")
            -- or --
            snap.ref.updateChildValues(["username": "xyz"])
        }
    })
}
```

I includes two options within the for loop. Only use one. The nice thing about updateChildValues is you can replace multiple values within the parent node at once if needed.